# Custom destructor in STL container

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say I have a STL vector whose elements are raw pointers to other classes. It's obvious that the destructor of the vector won't release the memory owned by these pointers. Is it possible to implement a custom destructor that releases this memory?

Comment: You'll need more than a destructor (and the rest of the Rule of Three); you'll also need to be very careful not to lose pointers by reassigning elements. For the gory details, see the implementation of Boost's pointer containers; in modern C++, just use `vector<unique_ptr>`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Whatever you do, don't use `unique_ptr` in a container.  Sooner or later, you're bound to do something like `auto x = v[i];`, effectively removing the pointed to object from the container.  If you must, use `shared_ptr`, but the Boost pointer containers are a much better solution, in the rare cases where the container should own the objects.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Are you thinking of `auto_ptr`, which (these days) you should never use for anything? Using unique pointers, `auto x = v[i]` shouldn't compile without an explicit `move`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Which will still cause problems.  One way or another, you find yourself in a situation where you cannot extract a value from the container.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I've no idea what you're talking about; I've never heard of any "problems" associated with using `unique_ptr` in a container, and it seems to me that that's an ideal use for them. `auto x = std::move(v[i])` will explicitly extract a value; `auto x = v[i]` won't compile.

Comment: @MikeSeymour In other words, nothing works normally.  Not a very good argument for `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The argument for `unique_ptr` is that it does exactly what the OP wants: automatically manages the lifetime of objects via pointers in a container. It's you that's trying to argue against it based on vague talk of "problems" illustrated by example code that doesn't even compile, and vague assertions that it doesn't "work normally", whatever that means. If you have a better solution, please write an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In modern C++, use `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`, and all the ownership issues are managed for you.

If C++11 isn't available, you could use `shared_ptr` (from Boost or TR1) rather than `unique_ptr`, or you could use [Boost's pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). (Don't try to use the deprecated `auto_ptr`, since that makes it far too easy to accidentally remove a pointer from the container. Presumably, the first comment is referring to this, but confusing it with the much safer `unique_ptr`.)

If for some reason you can't use these, or if you really want to do the work yourself, you'll need to wrap the vector in a class with:

- A destructor to delete each stored pointer;
- A copy constructor and copy-assignment operator, either deleted, or perfoming a "deep" copy; otherwise, there's a danger of two vectors thinking they own the same objects;
- Accessors to read and modify elements in such a way that you can't overwrite a stored pointer without deleting its object.

Comment: Using `unique_ptr` is a sure recipe for problems.  It does _not_ work well in containers, because things like `auto x = v[i];`, or `auto x = *iter;` will leave you with an invalide `unique_ptr` in the container.

Comment: @JamesKanze: No it won't, because that won't compile. `auto x = move(v[i])` would move a `unique_ptr` out of the container; but presumably that's the intent if you explicitly use `move`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I have not really use C++11 features, other than in toy programs, but my understanding is that `std::unique_ptr` was designed to solve this particular problem. What makes this a *bad* (or even the *worst*) solution?

Comment: @JamesKanze the only limitation I can see from the caller side WRT a vector of raw pointers is that you cannot copy elements, so in that sense it cannot be used blindly as a drop in replacement. But attempting that gives you a compiler error, which I think is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: I just realized there is a boost:ptr_vector that seems to suit my purpose. I guess it is more efficient than using a vector<unique_ptr<T>>.

Comment: @jbgs I'm not sure about efficiency, but whatever solution you adopt, you must be aware of its limitations.  Boost's pointer containers are, IMHO, the ideal solution when the only real reason for using pointers is polymorphism, but you still cannot safely copy the returned values without slicing.  `shared_ptr` more or less means that the readers should use `shared_ptr` too.  And `unique_ptr` more or less means that the readers have to extract the raw pointer if they want to keep the "value" around.

Comment: @juanchopanza It's less dangerous than I orignally feared, because you cannot simply copy the elements.  But what do you do with them?  (Actually, the more I consider the issues and the alternatives, the more I'm convinced that containers which own pointed to objects is a bad idea.  But sometimes, the alternatives are worse.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Good point. I read the doc carefully. boost::ptr_vector is not so suitable as I thought.

Answer (score 3):

No. You should clear elements manually, before destruction of vector. Something like

```
std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const T* p) { delete p; });
```

or you can use something like `boost::ptr_vector` (or some smart_pointers), that handle this case.

Comment: If you have C++11, using `std::unique_ptr` is cleaner than manually using a lambda for the cleanup.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Using `unique_ptr` is one of the worst solutions I can think of.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Could you elaborate? My understanding is that `unique_ptr` was specifically intended for this kind of situation.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I believe that the intent was for it to be usable in standard containers.  The problem remains that the whole design of the containers turns around value semantics, with the result that people following this idea will end up copying the elements of the container, one way or another (and possibly unintentionally).  And copying a `unique_ptr` does have unusual semantics.  The alternative solutions (Boost's pointer containers, or shared_ptr) are simply safer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I still don't follow your objections. Copying them doesn't have "unusual semantics"; they are simply uncopyable, and C++11 containers have been redesigned specifically to work with uncopyable value types. They can't be copied unintentionally, because they can't be copied at all. If your argument is "people who don't understand move semantics might be confused by move semantics", then that's true, but hardly an argument for avoiding them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the vector upon deletion and call the destructor of each element inside it

Or I guess the best option would be, instead of saving A*, save `shared_ptr<A>` and then when no one no longer points to A, it will be destructed

Comment: A small warning : std::vector has no virtual destructor.